# Maximum no. of books that can be held between two hands without the books falling down?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

The books are stacked horizontally against each other. Each book weighs 1kg(10N).
The coefficient of static friction between hand and book is 0.6 and between book and book is 0.4.
Each hand gives a normal force to the books of P=120N.

The prof. explained it as 2 cases, one where all the books are taken as a single body and another where 2 books were considered. But i couldn't get the correct answer(11).

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is clearly a conceptual question.

Answer (score 1):

If the books are in equilibrium the net horizontal force on each book must be zero. Since the hands exert a horizontal force of $120$ N on the two outer books then each book experiences a force of $120$ N from the left and an equal and opposite force of $120$ N from the right.

From the coefficients of friction that are given, you can work out the maximum static friction force that each book can experience - the value will be different for the two outer books than from any books in between them. Work out the static friction force that each outermost book must experience in order to support its weight. Then remember that if it experiences an upward static friction force from the book beside it, it must in turn exert a *downwards* static friction force on that book.

As long as the net static friction force (upward - downward) for each book is greater than or equal to that book's weight, then the book can be supported by friction.